# Why i get this Error : "The issuer of the security token was not recognized by the IssuerNameRegistry"

Tags: certificate, single-sign-on, wif, sts-securitytokenservice, ws-federation

When i want to run my application using a custom STS (I have written it and it works well), firstly i get this Error :

> ***The issuer of the security token was not recognized by the IssuerNameRegistry***

I tested all the solutions for this error but i still have this error.

I added the "TrustedIssuerNameRegistery" class and set it in web.config.

```
public class TrustedIssuerNameRegistery : IssuerNameRegistry
{
    string issuerName = string.Empty;
    public override string GetIssuerName(SecurityToken securityToken)
    {
        if (securityToken != null)
        {
            X509SecurityToken x509Cert = securityToken as X509SecurityToken;
            if (x509Cert != null && x509Cert.Certificate.SubjectName.Name == "CN=busta-ip1sts.com")
            {
                issuerName = x509Cert.Certificate.SubjectName.Name;
            }
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(issuerName))
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Untrusted issuer.");
        }

        return issuerName;
    }

    public override string GetIssuerName(System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken securityToken, string requestedIssuerName)
    {
        return base.GetIssuerName(securityToken, requestedIssuerName);
    }
}
```

this is the web.config setting :

```
<issuerNameRegistry type='Webapp1.TrustedIssuerNameRegistry' />
```

Then i get this Error :

```
***ID8030: The value of the 'type' property could not be parsed.Verify that the type attribute of '<issuerNameRegistry type="Webapp1.TrustedIssuerNameRegistry,webapp1">***
```

I even installed the **"ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry"** dll and registered it in web.config but i get the first error again.

Why i frequently get this error? What is wrong with it? What more can i do?
If you want , i can give you my source code too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you also need the assembly name: "WebApp1.TrustedIssuerNameRegistry, AssemblyName".

On a side note -- I hope that issuer name registry is only for testing -- it's insecure since anyone can create a cert with that subject name.

Comment: Yes, it's just for test